# Serving an NX monorepo of angular apps in Docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, nrwl-nx

I have an NX monorepo with 2 apps:

- Shop
- Landing

I wish to use docker-compose to run my entire environment with eventually some APIs and a database etc etc.

I created a docker-file that takes arguments and could be re-used to to run multiple angular apps in Nx:

```
# base image
FROM node

ARG APP


# # install chrome for protractor tests
# RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
# RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY decorate-angular-cli.js /app/decorate-angular-cli.js
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
RUN npm install reflect-metadata tslib rxjs @nestjs/platform-express

# add app
COPY . /app
# start app
CMD npm start $APP -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disableHostCheck=true --poll 100
```

and I created a docker-compose file that sets up an .net 5 API and the 2 web applications:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sletsgo.user.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sletsgo.user.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SletsGo.User.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:2000"
      - "444:443"

  sletsgo.shop:
    container_name: 'SletsGo.Shop'
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}sletsgo.shop:dev
    build:
        context: SletsGo
        dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        args:
            - APP=shop
    ports:
        - '4000:4200'
    #volumes:
    #    - sletsgo-web:/app
    #    - '/app/node_modules'

  sletsgo.landing:
    container_name: 'SletsGo.Landing'
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}sletsgo.landing:dev
    build:
        context: SletsGo
        dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        args:
            - APP=landing
    ports:
        - '4100:4200'
  #  volumes:
  #      - sletsgo-web:/app
  #      - '/app/node_modules'

 


#volumes:
# sletsgo-web:
#    driver: local
#    driver_opts:
#      type: local
#      device: ./SletsGo
#      o: bind
```

Please note that a lot of lines are commented out.
The issue is that if I run this docker-compose i get 2 instances of the shop application ran.

[image: screenshot showing 2 instaces of shop]

How can i fix this?

P.S. I also imagine that using volumes i might be able to simplify things a lot. But the mounting i tried failed because im using linux containers on a windows machine. If someone is willing to help me to that next level i would like that very much, but for now i just want to run both the web applications.

Comment: Try adding the following property to your landing service: `command: npm start landing -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disableHostCheck=true --poll 100`

Comment: Add it where exactlyt?

Comment: `services -> sletsgo.landing -> command: npm start landing -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disableHostCheck=true --poll 100`. The thing is, `APP` argument may be empty when you start the container. `command` in service definition overrides `CMD` from Dockerfile.

Comment: Do i then not use the dockerfile anymore?

Comment: No, you still need the Dockerfile but if it worked it proved that the problem is in argument missing. Did it help?

Comment: Persisting the [`APP` values in the environment during the build should solve the issue](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables). Otherwise you can [overwrite the `command` for both services in the `docker-compose.yaml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

Comment: why you need `--host 0.0.0.0` in the docker file if you are mapping the port in the Docker compose?

Comment: @anemyte your solution works! strange since when i had an echo in my dockerfile it would show it.  Couldnt i just remove the dockerfile all together if i had a volume mounted?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar Idk this is how i got it working before. maybe its redundant now.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar Doesnt work without d--host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TL;DR

[`ARG`'s are build time variables](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg). You can [persist the `ARG`'s value in the images environment during the build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables) or [override the `services[*].command` in the `docker-compose.yaml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command).

---

#### Persist in the environment

You can persist an environment variable set from a `--build-arg` in the images environment during the build:

```docker
FROM alpine:3
ARG APP
ENV APP=${APP}
CMD echo $APP
```

Build the `docker` image: `docker build --rm --build-arg APP=123 -t so:66935830 .`

Run the `docker` container: `docker run --rm -it so:66935830`

[image: docker run with environment variable set from --build-arg]

#### Override the `command`

You can override the `command` for each service in the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  a:
    image: 'a'
    build:
      context: '.'
    command: ['echo', '123']
  b:
    image: 'b'
    build:
      context: '.'
    command: ['echo', '456']
```

[image: docker-compose run command override]

Comment: Thanks for this lesson! very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Project Structure

apps

- ProjectA
- -ProjectB
- package.json
- packageLock.json
- decorate-angular-cli.js
- tsconfig.base.json
- nx.json

Create a Dockefile in root level

```
     # Use a specific version of the official Node.js image based on the slim variant
    FROM node:18.15.0-bullseye-slim AS build
    
    # Set the working directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/root
    
    # Copy required files for installing dependencies
    COPY package.json package-lock.json nx.json tsconfig.base.json decorate-angular-cli.js ./
    COPY libs/ ./libs/
    COPY apps/ ./apps/
    
    
    
    # Install npm dependencies
    RUN npm ci
    
    # Install nx globally
    RUN npm install -g nx
    
    # Set NX_DAEMON environment variable to false to prevent nx from running in daemon mode
    ENV NX_DAEMON=false
    
    # Build the application
    RUN nx run projectA:build
    RUN nx run projectB:build
    
    
    # Create a new stage for the runtime image
    FROM node:18.15.0-bullseye-slim AS runtime
    
    # Set the working directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/root
    
    # Copy build artifacts from the build stage
    COPY --from=build /usr/src/root/dist/apps/projectA /usr/src/root/dist/apps/projectA
    
    # Copy build artifacts from the build stage
    COPY --from=build /usr/src/root/dist/apps/projectB /usr/src/root/dist/apps/projectB
    
    # Expose ports
    EXPOSE 4200
    EXPOSE 4300
    # Install serve globally
    RUN npm install -g serve
```

Create a `docker-compose.yaml` in root level

```
   version: '3.4'
services:
  projectA:
    container_name: 'projectA'
    image: projectA
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:
      ['serve', '-s', 'dist/apps/projectA', '--listen', 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4200']
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
  projectB:
    container_name: 'projectB'
    image: projectB
    build:
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command:
      ['serve', '-s', 'dist/apps/projectB', '--listen', 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4300']
    ports:
      - '4300:4300'
```

run `docker-compose up` in root level.